# How to use Sprockets Rails plugin on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

I just deployed my Rails app to Heroku, but the Javascripts that were using Sprockets plugin don't work.

I understood that, because my Heroku app is read-only, Sprockets won't work. I've found this [sprockets_on_heroku](http://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku) plugin that should do the work, but I don't really get how to use it :

1. I added `config.gem sprockets` in config/environment.rb
2. I added `sprockets` in my .gems file
3. I pushed these on Heroku and Sprockets was successfully installed
4. I locally  ran `script/plugin install git://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku.git` and the plugin was successfully installed

Nothing changed on Heroku, so I tried to install the plugin on Heroku with `heroku plugins:install git://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku.git`, which returned `sprockets_on_heroku installed`but then, a `heroku restart`or a `heroku plugins`command would return this:

> ~/.heroku/plugins/sprockets_on_heroku/init.rb:1: uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/../lib/heroku/plugin.rb:25:in `load'
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/../lib/heroku/plugin.rb:25:in `load!'
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/../lib/heroku/plugin.rb:22:in `each'
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/../lib/heroku/plugin.rb:22:in `load!'
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/../lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `run'
>
> from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.8.3/bin/heroku:14
>
> from /opt/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
>
> from /opt/local/bin/heroku:19

What should I do?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprockets on Heroku's author Jeffry Degrande answered my e-mail. The only thing I should have done is to `git push heroku` **after** installing the plugin so that the files are deployed to Heroku. In short:

1. Add `config.gem sprockets` in config/environment.rb
2. Add `sprockets` in .gems file
3. Run `script/plugin install git://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku.git`
4. Push the changes to Heroku