# Sinatra app with sprockets not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, sprockets, ruby-1.9

I have a little Sinatra app including this module:

```
module Sprockets
  module Helpers
    def asset_path(source)
      "/assets/#{Environment.instance.find_asset(source).digest_path}"
    end

    def sprockets
      Environment.instance.call(env)
    end
  end

  class << self
    def precompile
      dir = 'public/assets'

      FileUtils.rm_rf(dir, secure: true)
      ::Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(Environment.instance, 'public/assets', [/\.(png|jpg)$/, /^(application|ie)\.(css|js)$/]).compile
    end
  end

  class Environment < ::Sprockets::Environment
    include Singleton

    def initialize
      super
      %w[app lib vendor].each do |dir|
        %w[images javascripts stylesheets].each do |type|
          path = File.join(root, dir, 'assets', type)
          append_path(path) if File.exist?(path)
        end
      end

      js_compressor = Uglifier.new
      css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new

      context_class.instance_eval do
        include Helpers
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and with following route defined:

```
get('/assets/*') do
  sprockets # Defined in the module above
end
```

Everything works just great, assets are loaded and displayed properly on my local machine using `pow`. But on Heroku no single asset is loaded, the server just returns 404 for every asset file.

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku, there is a similar [question for rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530584/how-to-use-sprockets-rails-plugin-on-heroku)

Comment: are you sure that this has something to do with sprockets? a 404 is indicating a missing resource. did you put your route somewhere it might not be recognized by heroku? is your config.ru file properly configured?

Comment: where did u get this `"/assets/#{Environment.instance.find_asset(source).digest_path}"` ??, which version of Sprokets ??

Comment: Latest version of Sprockets, and `Environment.instance` is the module above defined by myself.

Comment: @ream88 look into `production.rb` and change `config.serve_static_assets` to `true` , in production mode you can't serve static files

Comment: This is a Sinatra app, not a Rails app. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified the module and now it works! Weird...

```
class Assets < Sprockets::Environment
  class << self
    def instance(root = nil)
      @instance ||= new(root)
    end
  end

  def initialize(root)
    super

    %w[app lib vendor].each do |dir|
      %w[images javascripts stylesheets].each do |type|
        path = File.join(root, dir, 'assets', type)
        self.append_path(path) if File.exist?(path)
      end
    end

    self.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
    self.js_compressor = Uglifier.new

    context_class.instance_eval do
      include Helpers
    end
  end

  def precompile
    dir = 'public/assets'

    FileUtils.rm_rf(dir, secure: true)
    Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(self, 'public/assets', ['*']).compile
  end

  module Helpers
    def asset_path(source)
      "/assets/#{Assets.instance.find_asset(source).digest_path}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: newby question...how do I use this in sinatra..where to put this code/how do I add the javascripts/css/images to assets.js and assets.css..